# Read HEAD contents from HTML

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

i need small script in python. Need to read custom block in a web file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('http://target.com')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page # Here is all page source with html tags, but
               # i need read only section from <head> to </head>

# example the http://target.com source is:
# <html>
# <body>
# <head>
# ... need to read this section ...
# </head>
# ... page source ...
# </body>
# </html>
```

How read the custom section?

Comment: Parse it using a HTML parser such as BeautifulSoup. You will also get *easy* suggestions such as doing it with a regex, but don't make it a habit. Parse it.

Comment: You need to parse HTML/xhtml for it (if this is not a fast-cooked script to download something automatically from a site once).

Comment: @sukhbir I second that, it's infinitely more pleasurable (and generally better) to use an HTML parser.

Comment: You should know that the `<head>` and `</head>` tags are both optional.

Comment: @sukhbir: And here's why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
print soup.find('head')
```

outputs

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Example Web Page</title>
</head>
```

Comment: @Ernie Define what you mean by custom text?

Comment: if i need read text from "iv="Cont" to "charset=utf", not from html tags

Comment: @Ernie That's very different, you can do it with regular expressions quite easily. `re.search(r'"iv="Cont"(.*)"charset=utf"', text).group(1)`

Comment: @Ernie I think you can figure that out from what you've got.

Comment: NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: Try removing `import urllib2` from your code sample and rerun. What does this experiment suggest might be the solution to your `name 're' is not defined` error?

Answer (score 1):

To parse HTML, we use a parser, such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html).

Of course you can *parse* it using a regular expression, but that is something you should never do. Just because it works for some cases doesn't mean it is the standard way of doing it or is the proper way of doing it. If you are interested in knowing why, read this excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) on SO.

Start with the BeautifulSoup tutorial and see how to parse the required information. It is pretty easy to do it. We are not going to do it for you, that is for you to read and learn!

Just to give you a heads up, you have `the_page` which contains the HTML data.

```
>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>> soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page)
```

Now follow the tutorial and see how to get everything within the `head` tag.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the awesome python library [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). It allows you do parse the html/xml pretty easily, and will try to help out when the documents are broken or invalid.